# Send JavaScript date with milliseconds and timezone to Java webservice

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, date

I need to send my current date on UI as http request header to Java based webservice but facing issue as the javascript `new Date` method hides the millisecond data from date and forwards it to web service.

```
console.log(new Date())
LOGS - Thu Sep 07 2017 14:47:37 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

The millisecond information is not present. I however need that in a date type that Java webservice also considers as Date and not string. I read about momentjs format approach but that basically returns a string and not date.

What I need is like: `Thu Sep 07 2017 15:10:46:955GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

Comment: What is 900100? If you're talking about milliseconds, it should have just 3 digits.

Comment: @Hugo Yup corrected!

Comment: *momentjs returns a string and not date* - Read [**this**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date) - it talks about `java.util.Date` but the same concepts apply to JS date. **A date has no format and no timezone information**. It's just the number of milliseconds since epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`). The same date can be **represented** in many forms (or written in different formats). `console.log` just use one of the formats, `momentjs` allows [many others](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/), but all formats represent the same date value.

Comment: `console.log` doesn't show the milliseconds field, but it doesn't mean it's not there. You can call the `getMilliseconds()` method to check its value - it's just that `console.log`, for whatever reasons, doesn't show it. Another detail is that it uses the browser's timezone to display the value, but the date itself doesn't have timezone information as well. Anyway, if you're going to send a http request header, you'll probably need to send this as a string (unless you're using a lib that requires a date; in this case, just use the date object).

Comment: @Hugo Thanks much! Appreciate your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECMAScript Dates are based on a time value that is milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, so they are inherently UTC. Therefore the value returned by:

```
new Date().getTime();
// or more concisely
Date.now();
```

does not need a timezone and includes millisecond precision. You can also use *toISOString* which returns an ISO 8601 extended date with milliseconds, again using UTC, e.g. 2017-09-07T22:51:51.287Z.

The ISO format is very widely accepted, is conveniently human readable and is unambiguous.

However, if it's important to also convey the timezone of the source, you can use the timezone offset (which is returned in minutes to add to local time to get UTC) and format it to something more standard.

```js
function getISOOffset(date) {
  date = date || new Date();
  function z(n){return ('0'+n).slice(-2)}
  var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();

  // ECMScript offset sign is the reverse of ISO 8601
  var sign = offset < 0? '+' : '-';
  offset = Math.abs(offset);
  return sign + z(offset/60 | 0) + ':' + z(offset % 60);
}

console.log('The host offset is UTC' + getISOOffset())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with purely milliseconds you can use something like this:

```
Date.now(); // 1504785573971
```

This works on almost all modern browsers. It doesn't tell you the timezone of the user, but does give you a consistent number against which to compare (milliseconds since Midnight of January 1, 1970, GMT).

For the very specific timestamp you seek, you might need a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) - it's a pretty heavy solution, but gives you excellent control over formatting.

- [Moment.js Formatting Options](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

This *will be a string* as there is not truly agreed-upon formation for passing dates in JSON. It will require parsing logic in the Java. I don't have much experience on the Java side, but I believe the popular libraries like Jackson and GSON support this conversion.

If you are not using JSON to submit information to the server, normal form submissions are passed as a string and have to be parsed out on the server, anyway.

Comment: The timestamp does not convey timezone information - `GMT+0530` in this case.

Comment: I need timezone as well as milliseconds both!!

Comment: Since you are talking about a request header, MomentJS should be fine for the task... they are all essentially generated as text.

Comment: @Manu—ECMAScript time values are always UTC, no timezone required.